# Why a missing package statement does not give a compile time error in java?

Tags: java

I have been coding in java for about a year now and I discovered something strange. Consider the following project structure-

```
Project
|
|--src
   |
   |--Test
      |
      |--Class1.java
```

`Class1.java`

```java
public class Class1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Woah no package statement!");
    }
}
```

As you can see `Class1` has no package statement and Intellij actually gives an error -
`Missing package statement: 'Class1'`

I can compile and execute the main method through the command line as follows-

```sh
/Project/src/Test $ javac Class1.java

/Project/src/Test $ java Class1
Woah no package statement!
```

Now I know that when I try to run it through sources root, I will get an exception-

```sh
/Project/src $ javac Test/Class1.java

/Project/src $ java Test.Class1
Error: Could not find or load main class Test.Class1
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class1 (wrong name: Test/Class1)
```

Now I want to know the reason behind having such a design, why doesn't java straight away give a compile-time error if the package statement is missing **and** the class is not present in the default package.

Is there any use case for such type of design?

Comment: Why should it give an error? A Java class is just a class and doesn't care in what folder is in.

Comment: A class without a package declaration is in the default package. That means it is rooted in `/Project/src/Test`, instead of in `/Project/src` like when it has a `package Test` statement.

Comment: I can explicitly mark sources root, and most commonly `src` is marked.

Comment: @Tom Well I can't argue on that, but most of the IDE's and linting tools classify this as a smell.

Comment: They can apply their own stricter rules, but you ask about the core Java rules.

Comment: @Tom Hmm, I think you gave a pretty valid reason for this not classifying as a compile-time error, feel free to add it as an answer.

Comment: As @Tom said: how could `javac` possibly know that you wanted `Class1` to be in a package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering this with the suggestions from the comments to get it out of the unanswered questions queue:

`javac` can't know that you want `Class1` to be in a package if you compile it with

```
/Project/src/Test $ javac Class1.java
```

But Intellij will sure argue about that, given the folder structure you gave.